# how to change date from MM/DD/YYYY to MM-DD-YYYY using sed command

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have a file with dates like 01/01/2022 in a file that I need to change to 01-01-2022. I need to use the sed command to change the format (for a homework assignment).

So far I have tried:

```
s|([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})|\3-\2-\1|  file name
sed -e 's/([0-9][0-9]/])/([0-9][0-9]/)/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/)/\1-2-3\g'  file name
sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{4\}\)$/\1-\2-\3/'  filename
```

None have worked for me. I'm not sure what else to try, any suggestions would be appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: Take one example line out of the file, paste in into a regex tester website (there are many to choose from), select `sed`-compatible regular expressions, and edit your regex with instant feedback until it works.  Then try it at the command-line, on the whole file.

Comment: Why are you reversing the order in the 1st and last attempts?

Comment: Probably your `sed` doesn't understand `{2}` repetition. The longhand attempt failed because you forgot to backslash the parentheses and had other syntax errors. `s|\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)|\3-\2-\1|` should work with the most pedestrian `sed`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there …

This must be run as extended regex (`sed -r` or `sed -E`) and it outputs year-day-month:

```
s|([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})|\3-\2-\1|  filename
#                                  ^^^^^^^^-- likely want \1-\2-\3
```

The next has a stray closing bracket in the expression and could benefit from a different separator for the `s` command. Using `|` like in your first version avoids having to escape all slashes, which you are not doing. It's confusing forward slashes and backslashes too and must either escape all parentheses or use `-E`/`-r` and not escape any parentheses:

```
sed -e 's/([0-9][0-9]/])/([0-9][0-9]/)/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/)/\1-2-3\g'  filename
#                    || |           | |                      |     |||^-- must be a forward slash, not a backslash
#                    || |           | |                      |     ^^^-- must be \2-\3
#                    || ^-----------(-+-- must be escaped (or use a different separator)
#                    ^^--- stray closing bracket             |
#                                   ^------------------------+-- should be backslashes or removed (depending on whether using basic or extended regex)
```

And the last one should work, but only matches dates at the end of the line

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{4\}\)$/\1-\2-\3/'  filename
#                                                    ^-- matches only at end of line
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo '01/01/2022'|sed 's@/@-@g'
01-01-2022
```

And the case where other slashes are preserved:

```
$ echo 'abc/d 01/01/2022'|sed -E 's/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/\1-\2\-\3/'
abc/d 01-01-2022
```

Comment: OP seems to be making an effort to only replace the slashes found in dates, leaving any other slashes intact.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `-r` option for `()` and `{}` to work without escaping them. Then the first method works if you use `\1-\2-\3` as the replacement.

```
$ sed -r 's|([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})|\1-\2-\3|' <<EOF
foo 01/22/3456 bar
EOF
foo 01-22-3456 bar
```